# Binary operation between hexadecimal numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, hex

Is there any simple way in Ruby to operate with Hex numbers?

**[Updated 2017-02-23]** added background.

I created a ruby parser to analyse C code.
Background: The C code is automatically generated by a Python script that reads from a big configuration file. This Python script uses templates to create C and H files. Basically these C files are configuration for a C project.

The file contains macro definitions, arrays with parameters and operations like:

```
0X5EEA11 & 0X000100 // checking if the bit 8 is active
```

Since this code is safety relate the correctness of the code has to be ensure somehow, so I decided to use ruby to parse the generated file and compare them back to the original seeds (configuration files, which are excel lists with thousand of rows)

So I wonder if I have to convert it to binary and check bit a bit if the operation is correct.

I also check the result of the executable comparing that the mask was calculated correctly.

I saw how to convert to hex, but actually those are integers so I dont think I can do binary operation over them as if they were Hex.

Comment: What’s wrong with `0X5EEA11 & 0X000100`, or if you need an explicit boolean, with `(0X5EEA11 & 0X000100).zero? ? false : true`?

Comment: I parse them reading them as string, then I have to convert them to hex to operate, but using 0X5EEA11.hex returns an integer

Comment: But 0X5EEA11 *is* an integer in C and bitwise-& works on integers so...

Comment: Hexadecimal and Decimal display is just an external representation. Integers are always represented as binary internally.

Comment: Also, I often write this code as `0X5EEA11 & (1 << 8)` to make the intent clear.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Please, don't use ternary with two booleans as output. Either `!x.zero?` or `x == 1`

Comment: @SnakeSanders: What exactly do you want to check? If C calculates "bitwise AND" correctly? If Ruby calculates "bitwise AND" correctly? I suppose the answer to both is "yes". No need for a ruby parser analysing C code.

Comment: @EricDuminil I updated the description.
Anyway, I did some tests and you guys are right, it is possible to operate directly with the integer values of the Hex representation
Like so: 
var = "0X5EEA11"
var.hex & bit_mask.
How this question can be closed now?